# (Linux) iwatch executing python with special chars in filename

Tags: python, linux, character-encoding

I've set up iwatch to monitor some directory. Instead off emailing me, i want to execute my own script. Everything went well, until some special characters showed up.

iwatch -f iwatch.xml
where iwatch.xml is

```
[...]
<path type="recursive" alert="off" events="close_write" exec="commit '%f'">/user/Desktop/test</path>
[...]
```

commit programm:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import chardet,sys

print 40*"-" 
print chardet.detect(sys.argv[1])
print type(sys.argv[1]), sys.argv[1]
uni = unicode(sys.argv[1], sys.getfilesystemencoding())
print type(uni), uni
```

So, when i run "commit ÄÖÜäöüß", everything is fine

```
----------------------------------------
{'confidence': 0.99, 'encoding': 'utf-8'}
<type 'str'> ÄÖÜäöüß
<type 'unicode'> ÄÖÜäöüß
```

But, when it get fired from iwatch (touch ÄÖÜäöüß), i get

```
----------------------------------------
{'confidence': 0.99, 'encoding': 'utf-8'}
<type 'str'> /root/Desktop/test/ÃÃÃÃ¤Ã¶Ã¼Ã
<type 'unicode'> /root/Desktop/test/ÃÃÃÃ¤Ã¶Ã¼Ã
```

I don't know so much about encoding :/

How do I get my readable stuff here?

I've tried everything I could find (encoding/decoding in thousand ways) but didn't figuered it out. Can somebody help me? Every suggest would be appreciated! Thank you very much!

Comment: What if you try to omit single quotes like this: `exec="commit %f"`? Also try to use `iwatch`'s `-C` option to explicitly use `utf-8` encoding.

Answer (score 0):

New:

This dude wrote a patch for iwatch.

https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=608843

Both provided patches are working for me.

Patch 2 gives a ...pragma is deprecated... warning.

Old:

Changed strategy, I'll rebuild around pyinotify. This works great!

```
import pyinotify

wm = pyinotify.WatchManager()

mask = pyinotify.IN_CLOSE_WRITE

class EventHandler(pyinotify.ProcessEvent):
    def process_IN_CLOSE_WRITE(self, event):
        print "Wrote:", event.pathname

handler = EventHandler()

notifier = pyinotify.Notifier(wm, handler)

wdd = wm.add_watch('/root/Desktop/test', mask, rec=True)

notifier.loop()
```